# When posting OG content, how to choose only from Content Author's Groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

When a user is editing/creating a node, there is a field where the user can choose what groups to post the content to. I want this field to list only groups the user is actually a member of. Is there a setting for this? If there isn't, what is the best way to code this?

Comment: This should be the default behavior of a site using OG. Can you provide more details that may help figure out why this isn't the case in your configuration?

Comment: You aren't using user 1 when testing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is to provide all groups you have access. An administrator  account that has access to all the groups would get a list with all the groups. This happens, for example, with the user #1.

The only way to avoid that is not using an administrator account.